# Improve performance of a for loop comparing pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm facing a performance problem with Python/Pandas.
I have a for loop comparing consequent rows in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    if df.column_A.iloc[i] == df.column_A.iloc[i-1]:
        if df.column_B.iloc[i] == 'START' and df.column_B.iloc[i-1] == 'STOP':
            df.time.iloc[i] = df.time.iloc[i] - df.time.iloc[i-1]
```

Which is working properly, but is extremely slow.
My dataframe has around 1M rows, and I'm wondering if there is some way to improve performance.
I've read about vectorization, but I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: can you post a testable input fragment?

Comment: Can you generate some test data with expected outputs?

Comment: Can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Here's some test data:

`df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['A', 'START', 3], ['A', 'STOP', 6], ['B', 'STOP', 2], ['C', 'STOP', 1], ['C', 'START', 9], ['C', 'STOP', 7]],
    columns=['column_A', 'column_B', 'time']
)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `shift` and a `mask`:

```
mask = ((df.column_A == df.column_A.shift()) 
        & (df.column_B == 'START') & (df.column_B.shift() == 'STOP'))
df.loc[mask, 'time'] -= df.time.shift().loc[mask]
```

The mask select the row where the value in 'column_A' is equal to the value in the previous (obtained by `shift`) and where 'column_B' is equal to 'START' and the previous row to 'STOP'. Using `loc` allows you to change the value for all the selected rows by `mask` in the column 'time' by removing the value at the previous row (`shift` again) with the same mask in the column time

EDIT: with an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': [0,1,1,2,1,2,2], 'column_B': ['START', 'STOP', 'START','STOP', 'START','STOP', 'START'], 'time':range(7)})
   column_A column_B  time
0         0    START     0
1         1     STOP     1
2         1    START     2
3         2     STOP     3
4         1    START     4
5         2     STOP     5
6         2    START     6
```

so here the row number 2 and 6 meet your condition as the previous row has the same value in column_A and get 'START' in column_B while the preivous row has 'STOP'.

After running the code you get `df`:

```
   column_A column_B  time
0         0    START   0.0
1         1     STOP   1.0
2         1    START   1.0
3         2     STOP   3.0
4         1    START   4.0
5         2     STOP   5.0
6         2    START   1.0
```

where the value in time at row 2 is 1 (originally 2 minus value at previous row 1) and same for row 6 ( 6 - 5)

**EDIT for time comparison** let's create a df with 3000 rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [['A', 'START', 3], ['A', 'STOP', 6], ['B', 'STOP', 2], 
                    ['C', 'STOP', 1], ['C', 'START', 9], ['C', 'STOP', 7]],
                   columns=['column_A', 'column_B', 'time'] )
df = pd.concat([df]*500)
df.shape
Out[16]: (3000, 3)
```

now create two functions with the two methods:

```
# original method
def espogian (df):
    N = df.shape[0]
    for i in range(1, N):
        if df.column_A.iloc[i] == df.column_A.iloc[i-1]:
            if df.column_B.iloc[i] == 'START' and df.column_B.iloc[i-1] == 'STOP':
                df.time.iloc[i] = df.time.iloc[i] - df.time.iloc[i-1]
    return df
# mine
def ben(df):
    mask = ((df.column_A == df.column_A.shift()) 
        & (df.column_B == 'START') & (df.column_B.shift() == 'STOP'))
    df.loc[mask, 'time'] -= df.time.shift().loc[mask]
    return df
```

and run `timeit`:

```
%timeit espogian (df)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.71 s per loop

%timeit ben (df)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.79 ms per loop

# verify they are equal
df1 = espogian (df)
df2 = ben (df)
(df1==df2).all()
Out[24]: 
column_A    True
column_B    True
time        True
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested your code against my data, but is actually slower than my example

Comment: @espogian on your 1M rows data it's slower? I just added some time comparison on a `df` with 3000 rows and it's obviously faster

Comment: using timeit I collected different results. I'm still trying to understand why. However, my real goal was to improve efficiency about one order of magnitude. Don't know if it is possible

Comment: @espogian by the way, what is `N` in your code, I assumed it was `df.shape[0]` but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @espogian I just run my solution on a 3M rows dataframe and it took less than 1s. I don't know what was "extremely slow" in your question, but I think it's pretty fast :)

Comment: Then, there is something I'm not doing properly using your code. I need to spend some time practicing with it. BTW yes, df.shape[0] is N

Comment: I'm getting an error on the last operation:
`df.loc[mask, 'time'] -= df.time.shift().loc[mask]`
The error is the following: `descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'`

Comment: I have revised my code and now is working properly! My mistake, it was a dtype mismatch!!! Thank you for you precious assistance, this code really improved the performance a LOT!